# MacOS Mojave beta has limited display scaling on MacBook 12

Tags: resolution, mojave

Everything looks larger on my MacBook 12 after the latest Mojave update. It allows you to scale up the display to only one level (used to go up and down two levels). Has anyone noticed that? Any fixes yet?

Comment: It's actually out now. (: Are you still running a beta version?

Comment: ...or if you're still running beta, then 10.14.1 b1 is out; try that. Of course, if you **are** on beta, then you should report this to Apple too - the Feedback Assistant app's right there in your Dock. Also, please clarify the exact Mac model. There is no Macbook 2012.

Comment: Just upgraded to 10.14 b1 and no change. this happened since the upgrade to 10.14. I still could scale up two levels to get more spaces but now it only goes up one level.

Comment: you are not making sense

Comment: in Display Preferences, there were FIVE resolution scales to chose from (the Default res and two on either side). Now I get FOUR (Two choices to the left of the Default size, and only ONE on the right). The system is a 1st gen MacBook.

Comment: Maybe they decided the fractional scaling caused too much overhead? I assume you mean the first retina MacBook. I need to get one ready to send in for that keyboard repair program, I'll see if I get the same change after updating, but in the meantime, try option-clicking the radio button for scaled.

Comment: Option-clicking doesn't offer more choices. I agree with you on that it might have slowed down 1st gen MacBooks so much on Mojave that they got rid of it. In that case I'd have to revert back to High Sierra.